# How can I disable the menu option "Save As" on all browsers?

Tags: javascript

I blocked the CTRL/COMMAND button, for prevent CTRL+S, but if I go to "Menu > Save As..." all of my pages can be save on the computer. I need to block this function but I don't know how to do.

```
function alerta(){
    alert('A página não pode ser salva.');
    return false;
}
function verificaBotao(oEvent){
    var oEvent = oEvent ? oEvent : window.event;
    var tecla = (oEvent.keyCode) ? oEvent.keyCode : oEvent.which;
    if(tecla == 17 || tecla == 44|| tecla == 106){
        alerta();
    }
}
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2">
    document.onkeypress = verificaBotao;
    document.onkeydown = verificaBotao;
    document.oncontextmenu = alerta;
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: sorry. you cannot. put/manage/hide any sensitive data on the server.

Comment: No, you don't *need* to block that. And if you have to, you're not using the correct media for your application. If you don't want content to be copied, just use a PDF with disabled copy option.

Comment: @MaxArt and even that (PDF) isn't a robust solution.

Comment: @Pointy, even then, one could screenshot the content once viewed.

Answer (score 12):

There is no way for you to do this.  Once someone loads your page, it's already on their computer.  No point in trying to block this.

Even if you really wanted to do this, no browser will allow you to manipulate this functionality.